# Jmeter how can I use if controller to get the value of body data

Tags: jmeter

how can I make my if the controller works if the previous result on the HTTP request contains a value that I expected?

[HTTP Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tvvap.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMkQT.png)

I need the if works if the ${Param_S07_Teamboard} on the image is == to 3 for example

I tried the 3 options below but nothing working, its ignoring my if on the results

{"key":"tdm/assets-lastSelectedTeamboard","value":"3"} == '1'

{"key":"tdm/assets-lastSelectedTeamboard","value":"3"} == {"key":"tdm/assets-lastSelectedTeamboard","value":"3"}

"{Param_S07_Teamboard}" == "3"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMkQT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4JV0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAA8t.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all, [don't post code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).
2. How about just comparing your `Param_S07_Teamboard` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) value to `3`?
3. I also think you need to wrap the comparison into i.e. [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) as If Controller executes its child(ren) if the expression equals or evaluates to `true`

   ```
   ${__jexl3(${Param_S07_Teamboard}==3,)}
   ```
4. If you **really** need to get access to the previous HTTP Request sampler body data in the If Controller it can be done using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

   ```
   ${__groovy(ctx.getPreviousSampler().getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue(),)}
   ```

More information: [6 Tips for JMeter If Controller Usage](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller)